# Mostrar solo 2 decimales de un numero

Tags: java, android.studio

estoy haciendo una calculadora y quiero que me muestre solo los 2 últimos decimales.Ahora mismo me muestra todos los decimales ya sean 1 o 20.

En esta variable guardo el valor de la operacion realizada

```
double resultadofinal
```

Y luego con esto lo muestro en un textview

```
String mostrar = String.valueOf(resultadofinal);
txtresultado.setText(mostrar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de varias formas, una sería:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(df.format(resultadofinal));
```

Otra forma sería:

```
double resultadofinal = 123.456789;
String.format("%.2f", resultadofinal);
```